# Font for math paper

Tags: publishing

I need to write a paper for math and I don't know which font to use. I would like to use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAIDA.png) font, but I don't really know what font it is. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you going to publish the paper in a journal?

Comment: no, but I wanna find what font is that.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/font_typefaces

Comment: hmmm: are you sure this is a mathematical question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default font used in $\LaTeX$, a standard piece of software for document typesetting in mathematics and many scientific fields, is [Computer Modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern). This appears to be the font shown in your screenshot.

If you wish to learn LaTeX, there are many online resources and websites (such as [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/)) that will allow you to start learning and writing LaTeX code without needing to download anything; there is also a dedicated [StackExchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) devoted to the software.

Answer (score 1):

That font is Computer Modern, the default font for TeX and LaTeX.  Usually you type in some macro code and have it compiled:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
The point is that we're \emph{given} the beginning and the end, and somehow
we have to fill in the middle. But we can't just fill it in randomly -- we
have to fill it in with something that ``gets us to the end''.
\end{document}
```

gives you

[image: rendered latex]

Usually you'd use some LaTeX installation to use the font, but I think there font files for use in other applications.  I've never tried it, but I'm aware of https://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/